# What might cause ThreadAbortException when using HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Tags: .net

I'm living in nightmares because of this situation, I have a HttpWebRequest.GetResponse that keeps on giving me a ThreadAbortException, that causes the whole app to go down.

How can I avoid that, or at least handle it, would using Thread.ResetAbort() be useful in such a case?

To explain more here is a rough code sample:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://someurl.com/");
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
```

now the last line above throws the ThreadAbortException, it might be because the request timed out which is fine, but I don't want to get a ThreadAbortException inside my ASP.NET 2.0 app because it kills it. The ThreadAborException can't be caught with try/catch, the only way to handle it is using Thread.ResetAbort() which has its own bad effects too, it will keep the thread alive and god only knows for how long.

Comment: Try catching a System.Exception on the 2nd line there and see what type of ex is thrown.

Comment: You *can* catch ThreadAbortException, you just have to handle it correctly. ResetAbort() is the proper thing to do when you're done. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx for more.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what you say it seems you are making an outgoing WebRequest to an external resource from within the processing of an incoming request to an ASP.NET application.  There are (at least) two timeouts that are relevant here:

- WebRequest.Timeout (default 100000ms = 100s) specifies the timeout for execution of the outgoing WebRequest.  If this timeout expires, you should get a WebException - so this isn't your problem.
- The HttpRuntime that is processing your incoming request has an execution timeout: the default value according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) is 110s for .NET 2.0 or later, 90s for .NET 1.x.  When this timeout expires, you'll get a ThreadAbortException.  It looks like this is what is happening.

In .NET 1.x, you'd expect this, because the default HttpRuntime executionTimeout is less than WebRequest.Timeout.  In .NET 2.0, you'd expect this with the default timeouts if you have already spent >10s before making the outgoing WebRequest (e.g. if you have more than one outgoing WebRequest from within the same incoming request).

I would suggest you either:

- Reduce the WebRequest.Timeout for outgoing requests, and handle WebException, or
- If the outgoing requests can really take that long, then increase the httpRuntime execution timeout as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx).

Comment: httpRuntime.executionTimeout was the culprit in my scenario - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with using Response. Check out this article for some workarounds. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629

Also take a look at this MSDN documentation in the section for WebException and Remarks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

This exception can be caught... If you are having trouble detecting the right one, you should try catching a general exception (system.Exception) and from there the stack trace should tell you the specific type (HttpException, WebException, etc) to actually catch.

Answer (score 0):

Our application threw ThreadAbortException's all the time b/c of
Response.Redirect("url") calls. The app never closed, most likely b/c the exception was being caught at some point and remained active.

Incidentally, Response.Redirect("url",false) will prevent the Response from terminating with the exception. Andrew's post links to similar workarounds for different uses of the Response class.

Comment: This is accurate (Response.Redirect(url) calls Response.End which throws a ThreadAbortException) but not relevant to the OP's situation.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen both of the problems listed by Andrew and "ForCripesSake".

Another possibility for your ThreadAbortException is any code that runs outside the page request lifecycle on the server side, such as HttpModules and HttpHandlers.  Any exceptions thrown within a module or handler don't go to the default unhandled exception mechanism in ASP.Net, and can cause the thread to die.

There are a couple of exceptions that can't be handled easily in ASP.net or the CLR in general, according to this article:

[Reliability Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228970(VS.80).aspx)

Not sure if it applies to the client code you've listed in your question, but it might be related.

Hope that helps!